# Modding hardcoded calculations (Victoria 2)

Tags: assembly, disassembly

I am a modder* of Victoria 2** and I have come across a problem.
There is a hardcoded calculation in which a certain value is divided by another value. All I want to do is change this calculation from a division, to a subtraction.

I have downloaded a program called OllyDbg ( http://www.ollydbg.de/ ), with which I was able to turn the game's .exe into assembly code.

I have checked this coded for divisions (marked by 'div' there) and found 256.
There were several div dword cases, which I understand are double words and not the thing I am searching for, there are 62 div ecx cases which I think is the thing I should be looking at.

How do I figure out which division is the one I am searching for?
Is there an easier way to do this or is it more or less hopeless to try this?
I hope this community can provide the answers.

Note: I do not have any experience with the assembly language and this is all very new for me.

*(for the few who don't know) person who creates an edited version of a game

**A grand strategy pc game

EDIT: I should note that I know which 2 values are used for the calculations, both are dynamic and depend on the situation in the game. Could I possible use Cheat Engine to find which addresses the values have and use this to find the code I want to change?

Comment: Do note that division by powers of two can be also done with `shr`. Also, if the value is hardcoded (so, a constant in the source code used to compile the executable), the compiler probably changed it into [a sequence of shifts and multiplications](http://ridiculousfish.com/blog/posts/labor-of-division-episode-i.html).

Comment: There are so many ways this quest can go wrong! Good luck finding the needle in the haystack.

Comment: `DIV ECX` is also a double word case. The difference between that and `DIV DWORD PTR [something]` is that former divides by a 32-bit integer in a register and the later divides by a 32-bit integer in a memory location. If you don't understand x86 assembly well enough to know this already, I think your task might be hopeless.

Comment: Sadly, like mentioned, I lack the assembly knowledge :/ I had hoped it would be relatively easy to change 1 symbol, / --> - , but it seems it's more complicated and requires more knowledge. Maybe I'll be able to do it one day...

Comment: If you found the right insn, patching it from `div` to `sub` could work, except that `div` has two outputs: `eax` = quotient, `edx` = remainder.  Also, keep in mind there's an `idiv` insn (for signed-integer division), so the divide you're looking for might be one of those.  (If it isn't a shift or a sequence of other things, like @DanielKamilKozar suggests.)